# Async design / implementation

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I started recently to implement some `async` code in Python and I have some doubt about design and implementation.
For example, if I have to do some, let me call sync code as a non-`async` function, and I have just one `async` function, returning the coroutine is considered a bad habit or bad design?
Let me explain better with some code:

```
def my_async_function():
    #some sync code
    return async_code()
```

instead of:

```
async def my_async_function():
    #some sync code
    return await async_code()
```

Do you think the first version could hide some problems?
Or in general, every advice is appreciated because I'm new to this style of code.
P.S.: sorry for my English, I hope it's understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both variants are completely correct, but if in doubt, go with the second one. It will make it crystal clear to the caller that they are dealing with a coroutine, and a coroutine only.

There is a technical difference between the two, but it only becomes apparent if the caller doesn't await it immediately. Consider the following code:

```
aw = my_async_function()
# ... do something here ...
result = await aw
```

In your first example, "some sync code" will run as soon as you call the function, so if it has side effects, they will be visible in "do something here". In the second example, just invoking `my_async_function()` is completely side-effect-free, it only creates the coroutine object. In that variant "some sync code" executes only upon `await aw`, i.e. after "do something here" has already run.

Defining a coroutine as `async def` guarantees to the caller that no sync code will run before the coroutine result is actually awaited, which can be an important guarantee. Even if the function is not `async` and just returns an awaitable, it would be well advised to behave *as if* it upheld this guarantee, at least as far as the caller can observe it.

A well-known example that doesn't adhere of this principle is [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) which immediately submits the callable to the thread pool. For this reason `run_in_executor` can never be made an actual coroutine, because that would break code that calls it without bothering to `await` (or code that awaits only later, for whatever reason).

Comment: Oh sure, it's so obvious, I hadn't thought of it, thanks!